# PTX - difference between .local and .param

Tags: cuda, nvidia, ptx

I'm studying PTX and I don't understand the difference between `.param` and `.local` state spaces.

`.local` are variables visible to threads and stored on their stack (which is, by the way, thread memory)

`.param` are variables used for object allocation (if passing by value), function parameters and return values and input parameters and they're also allocated on the stack

On the PTX manual there's:

> In PTX, the address of a function input parameter may be moved into a
>   register using the mov instruction. Note that the parameter will be
>   copied to the stack if necessary, and so the address will be in the
>   `.local` state space and is accessed via `ld.local` and `st.local`
>   instructions.

I don't understand: why copying a `.param` to the stack if `.param` == `.local` and everything is already on the stack?

Comment: .param is a PTX-level abstraction for data passed from the host to the device as part of a kernel invocation, i.e. these are the kernel call parameters or arguments. In early GPUs, the actual storage used for this purpose was shared memory, in later GPUs this was changed to a constant memory bank.

Comment: @njuffa the poster hasn't come back with any additional questions based on your response, and your comment seems to me to be sufficient as an answer.  If you would post it as an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: @Robert Crovella Thanks I have copied the information into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.param is a PTX-level abstraction for data passed from the host to the device as part of a kernel invocation, i.e. these are the kernel call parameters or arguments. In early GPUs, the actual storage used for this purpose was shared memory, in later GPUs this was changed to a constant memory bank.